# SVG circle radius in path

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have SVG code to draw busy indicator.  How to reduce the radius of path so that cicle looks small in size?

```html
 <svg >
  <path fill="#000" d="M25.251,6.461c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615V6.461z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the viewbox of the SVG within your HTML.  Then you can change the size of the SVG within your CSS. See this guide https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ for more details and the snippet below I made as an example.

```css
#svgid1{
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#svgid2{
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color:lightskyblue;
}
#svgid3{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svgid1" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <path fill="#000" d="M25.251,6.461c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615V6.461z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>

<svg id="svgid2" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <path fill="#000" d="M25.251,6.461c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615V6.461z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>

<svg id="svgid3" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <path fill="#000" d="M25.251,6.461c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615V6.461z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>
```